# Wordpress: check whether the current post is in any of the specified terms

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, taxonomy

I have a custom post type `property` and a custom taxonomy `features`. On single `property` pages, I output all terms from `features`, including empty ones. However, I need to check which of these terms the current post is present in.

At the exit you need to get something like: `✓ cleaning` `X Internet` `✓ home phone`.

So, I get all the terms:

```php
$features = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'features',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]);
```

Then I try to sort them out and check if there is a current post in the term being checked.

```php
foreach ($features as $feature) :
    if (has_term($feature)) {
        echo '✓' . $feature->name;
    } else {
        echo 'X' . $feature->name;
    }
endforeach;
```

But I get:

`X cleaning` `X Internet` `X home phone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made a mistake, that's how it will work)

```php
foreach ($features as $feature) :
    if (has_term($feature, 'features')) {
        echo '✓' . $feature->name;
    } else {
        echo 'X' . $feature->name;
    }
endforeach;
```